# Best way to link two systems

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, ip, tunneling

I am trying to link two Ubuntu 20.04 servers together

Server One is a cloud server with its own dedicated IP with DDoS protection and a hardware firewall. Server Two is a much higher performance server, but it is at my home with no dedicated IP.

I would like Server One to be able to listen on Server Two's IP to be able to open things like a web server. Right now I am able to accomplish this with SSH forwarding (command below) as a systemd daemon, but I would like to be able to scale this better with the ability to use more ports without having to add a new systemd file.

```
ssh -N -R 3000:localhost:3000 user@serverone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try OpenVPN. It will be more complex to config though. But once connected, the other server's resource is completely open.

Comment: Thank you! I set this up and it works very well!